# Can I use Karabiner-Element or any other apps/workarounds to swap colon and semicolon in Sierra?

Tags: keyboard, macos, keybindings

Until OS X El Capitan, I used Karabiner to swap the colon with the semicolon.

However, at least until now, the Karabiner Element doesn't support a key swap where both of keys are based on the same root key (so for example, swap between delete and backslash works but swap between single-quote and double-quote doesn't).

Is there any other hacks in Karabiner-Element that enables this swapping, or any other apps or workarounds in macOS that enables you to swap a key that built on the same base key?

Comment: Actually by now (2018, K-E 12.1) it's _VERY_ easy to do key swaps that include modifier keys (here: "shift") . . . . . If you edit your `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json` file you'd just have to add after `"rules": [` this code: `{ "manipulators":[  {"from": {"key_code": "quote"}, "to": [ {"key_code": "quote", "modifiers": ["shift"]} ], "type": "basic"} ] },`. . . . . . As you see `"quote"`is mapped onto itself, adding `"shift"` to invoke the "second letter" (printed above the "basic one" on a keyboard key).

Comment: @clemsamlang Yes and I use Karabiner-Element now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Karabiner-Elements don't support the key swapping functionality. It only lets you remap some keys to others, and it is all it does right now.

[Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org) lets you swap keys, or lets you remap some keys or key combinations to others. You write in Lua to define whatever remapping you want.

Comment: I think you should include an example of the script for remapping a single key to give people a feel for the amount of learning and effort this involves.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a test and [TextExpander](http://textexpander.com/) will do exactly what you want. (Keyboard Maestro couldn't.)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make a custom layout with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Karabiner-Elements https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

You can find complex modification examples on https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/

There you can search, for example "semicolon", and you will find **Exchange semicolon and colon**
https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#exchange_semicolon_and_colon

When you click **Import** it will open Karabiner Elements and you just need to enable this rule.

Btw I copy `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json` to my git repository so I can easily track changes I made in configuration. You do not need to reload Karabiner Elements when you make changes in configuration.