# Is there any alternatives to Karabiner in Sierra, which lets you use whatever keybindings you like to open an application?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I have used Karabiner on El Capitan, but it is no longer working in Sierra. I used it to do whatever I like to do via keybindings, such as the followings:

- Open an application
- Switch to different languages
- Automatically back to English when I open Alfred
- Automatically back to English when I try to type in the search box in Chrome or Safari
- Open any folders in my filesystem
- Delete a character
- Move to the first or last part of the sentence

However, all of them are no longer working as Karabiner doesn't work in Sierra and the developer has not found much progress so far, which would likely take far more time to finally adjust to Sierra. I’ve not had success with [Karabiner elements and specific tasks like swapping the colon and semicolon.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277735/can-i-use-karabiner-element-or-any-other-apps-workarounds-to-swap-colon-and-semi)

So I would like to use any alternatives, if any, to let me set whatever keybindings I want to do the set of tasks above. Is there any such app or workarounds on system that makes it feasible?

Comment: I assume you've tested [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that [Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org) is suitable for these sets of tasks. You write your own keyboard remapping, application shortcut, etc... on `init.lua` script. Some Lua knowledge might be required but if you have any programming experience in other languages, it is not that difficult.

I have implemented all of the tasks on the question except `Move to the first or last part of the sentence`, and it sounds working well so far. It took me some time (around 20 hours) to fight with the script, though.

Answer (score 3):

You should try '[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)' as an Alternative. You can bind actions to different Application-States as Macros, f.e. when Application X is open, do Y etc.

They offer a Testperiod, so you can try before you buy and test if it is meeting your requirements.